# How to install couchbase in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: couchbase, ubuntu-16.04

I have a droplet at digitalocean. I want to install couchbase, but I didn't find ubuntu 16.04 community edition in https://www.couchbase.com/downloads

Need suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Try couchbase version 1.0.2

```
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-2-amd64.deb

dpkg -i /tmp/couchbase-release-1.0-0-amd64.deb
# Will install or upgrade packages
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential
```

follow [link](https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/c-sdk) for more details